# 複数のRakeタスクから呼び出されるモデルに依存しないメソッドの置き場所

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Railsのプロジェクトで定期処理を実行するrakeのタスクを

```
lib/tasks/foo.rake
lib/tasks/bar.rake
lib/tasks/hoge.rake
```

のように配置し、多重起動を禁止するために

```
namespace: foo do
  task :update_all, [:column] => :environment do |task, args|
    process_count = `ps -ef | grep #{task.name} | grep -v grep | wc -l`.to_i
    # whenever は `bash -c` を使って呼び出すため2個のプロセスが必ず出現する。だから3を使う
    next if process_count >= 3 
    # do task
  end
end
```

と書いているのですが、同様の処理はメソッド化したく、そのメソッドの置き場所をどこにするか迷っています。このような場合にはどこに置けば良いかという慣習はありますか？

#### 追記

私の説明が不明瞭だったので具体的に書かせていただきますと

```
def task_already_running?(task)
process_count = `ps -ef | grep #{task.name} | grep -v grep | wc -l`.to_i
        # whenever は `bash -c` を使って呼び出すため2個のプロセスが必ず出現する。だから3を使う
        if process_count >= 3 
end
```

というメソッドを定義して

```
namespace: foo do
  task :update_all, [:column] => :environment do |task, args|
    next if task_already_running?(task)
    # do task
  end
end
```

と書きたかったのですが、この `task_already_running?` というメソッドを定義するファイルの置き場所・方法になんらかの慣習的に置き場があるか知りたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

特にRailsとして規約は無いと思うので基本的に自由だと思います。
僕だったらこうするかな、という例を載せておきます。

```
# lib/tasks/cron.rake

namespace :cron do
  task :foo, [:column] => :environment do |task, args|
    Cron::FooRunner.new(task).run
  end
  task :bar, [:column] => :environment do |task, args|
    Cron::BarRunner.new(task).run
  end
  task :hoge, [:column] => :environment do |task, args|
    Cron::HogeRunner.new(task).run
  end
end

# app/models/cron/task_runner.rb
module Cron
  class TaskRunner
    def initialize(task)
      @task = task
    end

    def run
      process_count = `ps -ef | grep #{@task.name} | grep -v grep | wc -l`.to_i
      return if process_count >= 3
      do_task
    end

    def do_task
      # Override in sub classes
    end
  end
end

# app/models/cron/foo_runner.rb
module Cron
  class FooRunner < Cron::TaskRunner
    def do_task
      puts "update all with Foo"
    end
  end
end

# app/models/cron/bar_runner.rb
module Cron
  class BarRunner < Cron::TaskRunner
    def do_task
      puts "update all with Bar"
    end
  end
end

# app/models/cron/hoge_runner.rb
module Cron
  class HogeRunner < Cron::TaskRunner
    def do_task
      puts "update all with Hoge"
    end
  end
end
```

実行例はこんな感じです。

```
$ bundle exec rake cron:foo
update all with Foo

$ bundle exec rake cron:bar
update all with Bar

$ bundle exec rake cron:hoge
update all with Hoge
```

Githubにコードもアップしてあるので、手元で動かすこともできます。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/multiple-rake-sandbox

cron/xxx_runnerはmodelsの下ではなくlibの下に置く、というアプローチもあると思いますが、autoload_pathsの追加等が面倒なのでmodelsの下に置きました。
人によっては好みが分かれるところかもしれません。

以上、ご参考までに。

### EDIT

クラスの継承ではなく、ブロックを使うパターンも作ってみました。
こっちの方がシンプルかもしれません。

```
# lib/tasks/cron.rake
namespace :cron do
  task :foo, [:column] => :environment do |task, args|
    Foo.update_all(task)
  end
  task :bar, [:column] => :environment do |task, args|
    Bar.update_all(task)
  end
  task :hoge, [:column] => :environment do |task, args|
    Hoge.update_all(task)
  end
end

# app/models/cron/task_runner.rb
module Cron
  class TaskRunner
    def self.run(task)
      process_count = `ps -ef | grep #{task.name} | grep -v grep | wc -l`.to_i
      return if process_count >= 3
      yield
    end
  end
end

# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo
  def self.update_all(task)
    Cron::TaskRunner.run(task) do
      puts "update all with Foo"
    end
  end
end

# app/models/bar.rb
class Bar
  def self.update_all(task)
    Cron::TaskRunner.run(task) do
      puts "update all with Bar"
    end
  end
end

# app/models/hoge.rb
class Hoge
  def self.update_all(task)
    Cron::TaskRunner.run(task) do
      puts "update all with Hoge"
    end
  end
end
```

コードはこちらです。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/multiple-rake-sandbox/tree/with-block

なお、「同様の処理はメソッド化したく」の具体的な内容がハッキリわかっておらず、「たぶんこういうことかな？」と推測しながらこのコードを作っています。
もし、観点がずれていたら質問に追記してください。

### EDIT2

追記ありがとうございました。
この手の処理で慣習があるかどうかというと、無いと思います。（少なくとも僕が知る限りは）

なので、基本的にどんなやり方でもいいと思いますが、とりあえず別パターンの回答を追記しておきます。

```
# lib/tasks/rake_helpers.rb
def task_already_running?(task)
  process_count = `ps -ef | grep #{task.name} | grep -v grep | wc -l`.to_i
  process_count >= 3
end

# lib/tasks/foo.rake
require_relative 'rake_helpers'

namespace :foo do
  task :update_all, [:column] => :environment do |task, args|
    next if task_already_running?(task)
    puts "update all with Foo"
  end
end

# lib/tasks/bar.rake
require_relative 'rake_helpers'

namespace :bar do
  task :update_all, [:column] => :environment do |task, args|
    next if task_already_running?(task)
    puts "update all with Bar"
  end
end

# lib/tasks/hoge.rake
require_relative 'rake_helpers'

namespace :hoge do
  task :update_all, [:column] => :environment do |task, args|
    next if task_already_running?(task)
    puts "update all with Hoge"
  end
end
```

コードはこちらです。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/multiple-rake-sandbox/tree/multiple-rakes

Comment: 詳しい解説有難うございます。私が想像していたよりも手間がかかることになってしまうようですね…。したいことが不明瞭だったようなので具体的な記述を追記しておきました。

Comment: 追記していただいた `rake_helpers.rb` にメソッドを記述する方法が自分には一番わかりやすかったのでこの方法を使わせて頂きます。ありがとうございました。